# Implementation of an abstract data type in C using typedef

Tags: c, struct, typedef, abstract-data-type

So I am looking at a snippet of C code in one of my books, relating to the implementation of Abstract Data Types using the 'typedef' operator:

```
struct account {
  char *username;
  char *password;
};

struct account;

typedef struct account *Account;
```

Would someone please explain to me what is the purpose of this part:

```
struct account;
```

I'm not sure what its use is here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
struct account;
```

Looking at your code, it is not really necessary. But it can be useful as **forward declaration**, when  you do not have complete definition yet available, and you are using pointer of type `account` and define it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a forward declaration. This goes to the public header:

```
struct account;
typedef struct account *Account;
```

so `Account` type is usable out there, but the struct members are hidden.